# How to slidetoggle div by setting visibility property to hidden?

Tags: jquery

I have this element:

```
<div id="propertiesArea"><div id="closeProperties"></div>some content</div>
```

I need to slidetoggle it using JQuery by set CSS  visibility property to hidden.
 Here what I try:

```
$('#closeProperties').click( function(){    
        $('#propertiesArea').toggle('slide');        
    });
```

But it's not works. Any idea how can I slidetogglethe element by set visibility property to hidden?

Comment: Where in this code did you set the CSS visibility to hidden? I only see a class toggle (and there is no CSS code in your example, so we don't even know what this class contains)

Comment: Shouldn't it be <div id="propertiesArea"><div id="closeProperties"></div>some content</div> or there's code missing ?

Comment: the parameter of `toggle()` defines the duration, so either `slow`, `fast` or a number or a boolean to show or hide the element. What you probably are looking for is `slideToggle()`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the hide method to manage the div's visibility?()

```
$('#propertiesArea').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think forst you need to crrect your html

```
<div id="propertiesArea">
 <div id="closeProperties">
  <div>some content</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

the actual toggle code is as below

```
$( "#closeProperties" ).click(function() {
  $( "#propertiesArea" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

as per your above logic, you will not able to show the div again as you are hiding the parent div.

Comment: Toggle will set display paramentr to none, I need to avoid it!

Comment: Then try to use .show() and .hide(). jQuery have these methods

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution, check your HTML code:

```
<div id="propertiesArea"><div id="closeProperties">some content</div></div>
```

and JS

```
$('#closeProperties').click( function(){    
    $('#propertiesArea').css('visibility', 'hidden');       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest code to toggle.

```
$('#closeProperties').click( function(){    
    $('#propertiesArea').toggle(":visible");       
});
```

Or

There is one more function available in jquery called `slideToggle`

```
$('#closeProperties').click( function(){    
    $('#propertiesArea').slideToggle("slow"); // you can pass milliseconds or "fast"/"slow" keywords       
});
```

The difference is `toggle` just hide and show the element and `slideToggle` also hide and show the element but with sliding motion.

Comment: your will set display paramentr to none, I need to avoid it!

Comment: @Michael So what do you really want to do with it.